# Appium -Issue in Xpath object recognition

Tags: android, xpath, appium

I am getting this below error while executing my first appium program:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

The above error is occurring because of the below code:

`driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']").click();`

Please help me understand the issue.

Comment: Can you share the list of JARs that you have added in this project?

Comment: Hi Anish,                                                                                                         I have included all the seleniumjars-2.53, Libs And java-client-5.0.0-BETA9.jar

Comment: Can you try Selenium 3.4 and Java client? I'm not sure if Selenium 2.53 would work. It mostly looks like some setup related issue (some missing libraries). If you need complete steps for setup, then please check this link - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-jars-download/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I tried using appium with testobject's reporter.

I solved the issue by adding

```
testCompile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '21.0'
```

to my gradle dependencies.

It seems as though the testobject reporter was using a version of guava that was incompatible with selenium.

Full dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8'
    compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '5.0.4'
    testCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.53.0'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
    compile group: 'org.apache.clerezza.ext', name: 'org.json.simple', version: '0.4'
    testCompile 'org.testobject:testobject-appium-java-api:0.1.0'
    //this is here to overwrite the guave dependency from the testobject repo. If not overwritten, causes error
    testCompile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '21.0'
}
```